# Powershell how to get acls from files/directories recursively also including "[" or "]"

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs

I have the script below working for most of the files and folders but is not working for files and folders with "[" "]"

```
#Set variables
$path =  $args[0]
$filename = $args[1]
$date = Get-Date

#Place Headers on out-put file
$list = "Permissions for directories in: $Path"
$list | format-table | Out-File "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"
$datelist = "Report Run Time: $date"
$datelist | format-table | Out-File -append "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"
$spacelist = " "
$spacelist | format-table | Out-File -append "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"

#Populate Folders Array
[Array] $folders = Get-ChildItem -path $path -force -recurse 

#Process data in array
ForEach ($folder in [Array] $folders)
{
#Convert Powershell Provider Folder Path to standard folder path
$PSPath = (Convert-Path $folder.pspath)
$list = ("Path: $PSPath")
$list | format-table | Out-File -append "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"

Get-Acl -path $PSPath | Format-List -property AccessToString | Out-File -append "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"

"-----------------------" | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename" -Append

} #end ForEach
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure this does 100% the same thing but I'm using the following one-liner

```
get-childitem "C:\windows\temp" -recurse | get-acl | Format-List | Out-File "c:\temp\output.txt"
```

Comment: This posting is the only one on this page that I can get to work.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the `Convert-Path` cmdlet trying to "interpret" the path including the square brackets which it "interprets" as wildcard characters. Instead you want to have it use the literal path.

Change this line:

```
$PSPath = (Convert-Path $folder.pspath)
```

To this:

```
$PSPath = (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $folder.pspath)
```

Also, change the `Get-Acl -path` to `Get-Acl -LiteralPath` so it looks like this:

```
Get-Acl -LiteralPath $PSPath | Format-List -property AccessToString | Out-File -append "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"
```

If you don't have PowerShell Version 3.0 (where Get-Acl added -LiteralPath support), you can use Get-Item as a workaround:

```
$item = Get-Item -LiteralPath $PSPath
$item.GetAccessControl() | Format-List -property AccessToString | Out-File -append "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"
```

For more information see this article: [LiteralPaths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but it looks like by modifying it with $PSPath = (Convert-Path -LiteralPath $folder.pspath) the script only works for the root of the folder and is not grabing acls recursively,

Comment: Please see above for the edit. You also have to change the Get-Acl -Path to Get-Acl -LiteralPath as well, otherwise the Get-Acl will choke on the square brackets as well.

Comment: Thanks but looks like get-acl does not support LiteralPaths,

Comment: Graham Gold beat me to it.. Get-Acl -LiteralPath was introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849802.aspx)

Comment: @HAL9256 thank you for this answer. It may be worth noting that the GetAccessControl() method exists on PowerShell v1, but it returns $null for some reason. However, the technique works great on PowerShell v2.

Answer (score 1):

`get-acl` support for `literalpath` wasn't added until Powershell V3.

If you're stuck using an earlier version and for whatever reason can't upgrade to V3, go with @HAL9256 suggestion for `convert-path` but for the `get-acl` part this should work instead:

```
((Get-Item -LiteralPath $PSPath).GetAccessControl()).AccessToString | Out-File -append "C:\Powershell\Results\$filename"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change to @peter's one-liner. it speeds it up quite a bit:

Get-Childitem "C:\windows\temp" -folder -recurse |
get-acl | Export-CSV "c:\temp\output.csv" -notype -append